# block.number during development

Tags: contract-development, testing

I am developing a code that verify if a period of time has passed. I do not need precision. Just to check if aproximately 1hour has passed.
I am using block.number. But, I noticed that it is not working as expected in a simulated blockchain (development). In other words, it is not incremented at each 15seconds. I think it increments when a transaction is sent to the network. 
Does it make sense? Does anyone has experience with that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right.

Blockchain emulators like Remix's JavaScriptVM and Truffle's ganache "mine" blocks *on demand* to process sent transactions quickly but they don't produce blocks at all if nothing is happening.

There are a few approaches to consider at different stages of testing. It might be sufficient to just be aware of this and monkey hammer the chain with "do nothing" transactions in order to force things to move forward in a preliminary test.

Alternatively, you can set up a private single-node ethereum network with a very low difficulty. When I do that, I get about two blocks/second. The obvious advantage there is the test suite doesn't need to be contaminated with steps that are nonsense on a "real" chain.

Since you say you don't need precision, it might also make sense to refer to the `block.timeStamp`. That might look something like:

```
uint deadline = now + 1 hour;

function isPastDeadline() public view returns(bool isIndeed) { ...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ganache in the present version has the automine feature: every N seconds a new block is generated. If you are using windows version with UI (that is at 1.22 version at the moment) and look in settings page, it is very easy to do. If you want to simulate Ethereum blockchain rate, simply ask a new block every 15 seconds.